# Favoriting an item through the console

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to set an item as a favorite through the console?

I'm trying to add a bound sword and bound bow to my inventory and actually have access to them without doing a `player.equipitem` every time. They don't seem to show up in my inventory so I can't favorite them that way.

I'm not interested in mods that accomplish this bound-item function, just a way to favorite an item through console.

Comment: You want quick access to a Bound Weapon, without going through the trouble of casting the spells?

Comment: Do they not equip to your hands when you cast the spell?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You can favorite items by pressing the Y button on the item you wish to favorite. After that you can access your favorites at anytime by pressing UP on the D-PAD.

Secondly: Bound weapons are conjured weapons. Summoned through the use of Conjuration magic"

Not sure exactly what you are asking exactly however **you will not find the bound sword or bow in your inventory for weapons as it is a spell**. The only way to accomplish what you want is to favorite the *Bound Sword* Spell.

This way you will have access to the spell in your favorites and will have to recast it when the 120 second effect ends or you sheathe your weapon.